# onsubmit Function Issues

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

As I have almost no knowledge of HTML and I had no idea where to ask, I decided to come here. I am trying to edit HTML Weebly web editor generated and add a "contact us" form which will direct messages to my email. I found some source code on the web and tried to incorporate it with the form Weebly generated for me, however I have not had any success. My code is below:

```
<div>

     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contactform" method="post" action="" onsubmit="myFunction()">
     <div id="466589977852666939-form-parent" class="wsite-form-container" style="margin-top:10px;">
     <ul class="formlist" id="466589977852666939-form-list">
     <h2 class="wsite-content-title" style="text-align:left;">SEND US AN EMAIL</h2>

     <div><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
            <label class="wsite-form-label" for="Email_Address">Email <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
            <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
                <input id="Email_Address" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" type="text" name="Email_Address" maxlength="100" />
            </div>
            <div id="instructions-270584481949385592" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
        </div></div>

     <div><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
            <label class="wsite-form-label" for="Your_Message">Your Message <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
            <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
                <textarea id="Your_Message" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" name="Your_Message" style="height: 200px"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="instructions-137987539423347553" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
        </div></div>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="text-align:left; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <input type='submit' style='position:absolute;top:0;left:-9999px;width:1px;height:1px' /><a class='wsite-button' ><span class='wsite-button-inner'>Submit</span></a>
</div>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
}
</script>

</div>
```

It obviously has something to do with the button click not being registered, so I made my own much simpler form to test it out.

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="" onsubmit="myFunction()">
<table width="400px" class="contactform">
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Email_Address" class="required">Email Address<span class="required_star"> * </span></label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="Email_Address" id="Email_Address" maxlength="100" style="width:230px">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="Your_Message" class="required">Your Message<span class="required_star"> * </span></label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <textarea style="width:230px;height:160px" name="Your_Message" id="Your_Message" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center" >
    <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value=" Submit Form " style="width:200px;height:40px">
        <br /><br />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


<script>
    function myFunction() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
    }
</script>
```

And in this case, the function actually fired! So now I am unsure as to what the difference is between my first example, and my second much simpler piece of code. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an `onclick()` to the submit `<a>` tag to submit the form.

Like so, change...

```
<a class='wsite-button' ><span class='wsite-button-inner'>Submit</span></a>
```

To...

```
<a class="wsite-button" onclick="document.contactform.submit(); return false;"><span class="wsite-button-inner">Submit</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your simplified example you used a Submit button.

Where as in you original form the button is moved out of the screen using CSS and only the text 'Submit' is left there. And your function triggers when the *input* is clicked, not the text.

This is the CSS style attributes that are hiding the button:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -9999px;
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
```

Replace this:

```
<input type="submit" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:-9999px;width:1px;height:1px">
```

By this:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

The button will reappear and clicking on it will trigger your message box.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/2tw5enb7/)